# Error: parameter for <variable> is initialized in C

Tags: c, gcc, parameters

I am currently getting a strange error when I try to compile my C code:
when instantiating and assigning a variable, the compiler claims an error that the parameter is already initialized:

```
tasks.c: In function ‘hashfunc’:
tasks.c:7:1: error: parameter ‘DESIRED_HASH’ is initialized
char* DESIRED_HASH = "e65493ccdee9c4514fe20e0404f3bcb8";
```

For line 9, I get: error: storage class specified for parameter "word_entry"

My code:

```
#include "md5.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "hash.h"

const char* DESIRED_HASH = "e65493ccdee9c4514fe20e0404f3bcb8";

typedef struct word_entry {
    char* word;
    word_entry* next_word;
}word_entry;

typedef struct result {
    char* a;
    char* b;
}result;

int word_count = 0;

void add_word(word_entry* head, char* new_word)
{
    word_entry* entry = head;

    while(entry->next_word != NULL)
    {    
        if(strcmp(entry->word, new_word) == 0)
        {
            return;
        }

        entry = entry->next_word;
    }

    word_entry* new_entry = malloc(sizeof(word_entry));
    new_entry->word = new_word;
    new_entry->next_word = NULL;

    entry->next_word = new_entry;

    word_count++; 
}

char* get_word(word_entry* head, int index)
{
    word_entry* curr = head;

    for(int i = 0; i < index; i++)
    {
        curr = curr->next_word;
    }

    return curr; 
}


int main(){
    char* words = "das sind die woerter ( ginge auch als methoden parameter )";

    word_entry* head = NULL;

    char* tok = strtok(words, " ");
    head = malloc(sizeof(word_entry));
    head->word = tok;
    head->next_word = NULL;

    tok = strtok(NULL," .,;-:0123456789?!\"*+()|&[]#$/%%’");

    while(tok != NULL)
    {
        add_word(head, tok);      
        tok = strtok(NULL," .,;-:0123456789?!\"*+()|&[]#$/%%’");
    }
    printf("%d words\n", word_count);

    char** pWords = malloc(sizeof(char*) * word_count);

    word_entry* entry = head;

    for(int i = 0; i < word_count; i++)
    {    
        pWords[i] = entry->word;
        entry = entry->next_word;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < word_count; i++)
    {   
        for(int j = 0; j < word_count; j++)
        {    
            char* first_word = pWords[i]; // oder get_word(i)
            char* second_word = pWords[j]; // oder get_word(j)

            char* result = hashfunc(first_word,second_word);
            int res = strcmp(result,DESIRED_HASH);
            if(res==0){
                printf("%s and %s lead to the hash",first_word,second_word);
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

What may be the error here?  I would be thankful for any kind of help as I'm currently stuck here.  I suspect a syntax error, but am not sure.

Thanks in advance.

PS:
"Hash.h" consists of:

```
extern char* hashfunc (char* word1, char* word2)
```

"Hash.c":

```
#include "md5.h"
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char* hashfunc (char* word1, char* word2){

    MD5_CTX md5;
    MD5_Init(&md5);

    char * word = (char *) malloc(strlen(word1)+ strlen(word2) +1);
    strcpy(word,word1);
    strcat(word,word2);

    MD5_Update(&md5,word,strlen(word));

    unsigned char* digest = malloc(1+ (sizeof(char)* 16)); 
    MD5_Final(digest,&md5);


    char* str = malloc(32*sizeof(char));

    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++){
        sprintf(str+2*i, "%02x", (int)(unsigned char)digest[i]);
    }

    free(word);
    free(digest);
    return str;
}
```

Comment: It might be useful to know what `"hash.h"` looks like.

Comment: Does changing `char* DESIRED_HASH` to `char const * DESIRED_HASH` make a difference?

Comment: @StoryTeller unfortunately no

Comment: That's `"md5.h"`, not `"hash.h"`. I asked about the include file, because I suspected that something at the end trips up what comes after the `#include` in the main file.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I'll edit the first post accordingly.

Comment: Also the error mentions `hashfunc`. Your code does not contain it.

Comment: A-ha. Your header should include prototypes, which should end with a semicolon.

Comment: That solved most of the errors. One stayed. In tasks.c 100: error expected declaration or statement at end of input

Comment: OT:  the expression: `sizeof(char)` is defined in the C standard as 1.  Multiplying anything by 1 has no effect.  Suggest removing that expression in the calls to `malloc()`

Comment: @user3629249 will do. Thank you.

Comment: regarding: `extern char* hashfunc (char* word1, char* word2)`  This is missing a trailing ';' so the compiler will treat any lines following that statement as part of the function: `hashfunc()`  Suggest appending a ';' to that statement, so it is seen as a function prototype rather than the actual function

Comment: in function: `get_word()`, the returned type is `char*`, but the actual returned value has type: `word_entry*`   Your compiler should have told you about this problem

Comment: And when executing I get a segmentation fault.

Comment: It is good programming practice to use 'include guards' around the body of a header file.  For instance in hash.h: `#ifndef HASH_H  newline #define HASH_H`  and at the end of `hash.h` the statement: `#endif // HASH_H`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `#include` directive just "pastes" the according file into the source code in a preprocessing step before the actual compilation. In your case, the file looks like this after preprocessing.

```
extern char* hashfunc (char* word1, char* word2)

char* DESIRED_HASH = "e65493ccdee9c4514fe20e0404f3bcb8";

typedef struct word_entry {
    char* word;
    word_entry* next_word;
}word_entry;
```

This is apparently interpreted as the old K&R style of function declaration, where the types of arguments are declared after the argument list and before the function body in `{}`.

Your header ´hash.h` should only contain the prototype of the function without a body. To fix your error, end the definition of the function with a semi-colon:

```
extern char* hashfunc (char* word1, char* word2)
```

It is also good practice to include `hash.h` from the implementation in `hash.c` in order to rule out mismatches between the prototype and the actual implementation.

As to the additional question you askes in the comments: A type is not known until the `typedef` has ended. That means you must define a pointer to the struct you're typedeffing with the `struct` keyword:

```
struct word_entry* next_word;
```

or, and I like that variant better, you can separate `typedef` and `struct` definition:

```
typedef struct word_entry word_entry;

struct word_entry {
    char* word;
    word_entry* next_word;
};
```

(The `typedef` can be in a header and the `struct` in the implementation file.)